# WP All Import - Convert date to a unix timestamp when importing via a php function

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, wpallimport

I am using WP All Import plugin for Wordpress and trying to import a date cell but I need it converting from a user friendly date to a unix timestamp.

```
23/04/2021 13:50
```

to

```
1606694400
```

WP All Import allows me to run a php function when importing into a custom field. I have found we can use the following within php:

```
strtotime()
```

I also found the below link to suggest a method of using inline php with the plugin but it's using a price example.

https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/custom-code/inline-php/

My column containing dates is called **Date** which the plugin would map data to using:

```
{date[1]}
```

Comment: What's not working? You listed all the parts for your solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this using the below method:

```
[strtotime(str_replace("/",".",{date[1]}))]
```

The above goes into the custom field you want to import the date to and not the PHP Custom Functions tab.

In my case, I was importing dates for products that are on pre-order. Remember to change the end part:

```
{date[1]}
```

To your column name.

Image preview is below, however, please note there is **NO line break** despite it showing it that way.

[image: Image preview of how to input the code]

Comment: Thank you, I was having the same issue, and that solves the problem.